# How to set two line text in UITabbar (Using Storyboard) in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, text, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

Currently i am working in iPhone applications, Using Storyboard to create tabbar app in iPhone, then i set text like download images, download books, download musics etc.. finally i run thae application, it seems to stretch all tabbar items, but i want to set text two line like "Dowload" as first line and "books" as second line in each tabbaar item, How to do this? please help me

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: Can u please give any simple example for this

Comment: do study this - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html